Collision parameter for extended rigid bodies
Recently, I was introduced to the concept of "coefficient of restitution" in collisions. My understanding of the concept is that :
$$e = {\frac{\text{Relative velocity of separation}}{\text{Relative velocity of approach}}}$$
My question is, what happens if the bodies are not point objects? Is the coefficient of restitution equation even applicable in such cases?
Take a rod on a table, free to move and rotate. If a ball comes and hits it such that the rod begins moving translationally as well as rotationally, what would be the relative velocity of separation?
Is it the relative velocity of separation of the centres of mass of the objects, or the separation of the point of impact and the ball?
Additionally, I also came across this:
$$e = {\sqrt{\frac{\text{Total kinetic energy after collision}}{\text{Total kinetic energy before collision}}}}$$
For applying this for collisions of extended rigid bodies, do I need to take into account, ALL he kinetic energy of the system, including translational and rotational?

The coefficient(s) of restitution that you define is (are) the simplest of many models that are out there.  Other models have been proposed by Brach, Routh, and others over the years to account for complicating factors like mass distribution, friction, etc.  Like friction coefficients, these models are relatively crude representations of complicated surface interactions, local deformations, compressive wave effects, and maybe other things.  As you note from your two equations for $e$, they can have different definitions; although your first definition of $e$ is the most popular one taught in schools, there is no one "right" model.
For some background discussion and another alternative two-parameter law, I suggest googling the following paper: "A New Algebraic Rigid Body Collision Law Based On Impulse Space Considerations" by my former colleagues A. Chatterjee and A. Ruina.

So if I have been given that e=1 for a collision, you're saying that I can't conclude much from it? If that's the case, why do we even talk about such an information? Additionally, please tell me what one would mean by an "elastic" or an "inelastic" collision.

It depends a little on the context but for the purposes of a physics class, if you are told that $e=1$ you can assume that the collisions conserve energy and are non-sticking.  This is the equivalent to saying "perfectly elastic."  For your rod example, that would mean that the pre-collision energy was equal to the post collision energy, which would include linear and angular contributions.  The "relative velocity of separation" can be either of the things you mention - in other words, whatever you define it to be.  If a questions asks you for it with no definition, it is an unclear question.
